# Spring 3.0.1 adding mvc:resources to include css in jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have got a web application which uses spring framework - version 3.0.1 release. I tried to add CSS to the jsp files in that project. I am a web developer and new to spring. I have gone through all suggestions listed out and found that not useful. Everyone suggesting to use mvc:resource. But when I add that in my servlet, I get the below error

"the matching wildcard is strict but no declaration can be found for element mvc:resources"

So, 3.0.1 supports mvs:resources?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you upgrade to Spring 3.2?
2. Put your JSP files in `/webapp/WEB-INF/views`
3. Put your static resources like CSS files in `/webapp/static`
4. You will want this in your Web Application Context Configuration (usually `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`):

   ```
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />

   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
   ```

In JSP files, you would then refer to your CSS files like this;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/static/my-stylesheet.css'/>">
```